# How to make my Activity as Full Screen mode in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an App and SDK, both are different. I included my SDK into my App. Now the problem is I have issues with making my activity in fullscreen. In SDK, classes are NON-Activity class there is no GUI, only backend Process. so I want to make them Full screen view. Here I can not use:

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Because my activity Non-activity class so there is no more window.so plan to use this code,

```
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        htmlAd.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
        {
            @JavascriptInterface           
            public void performClick(String strl)
            {
                Activity activity = (Activity) adViewContext;
                if(strl.equals("base")){
                    View mDecorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
                    Toast.makeText (activity, "ONE" + strl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
                }else{
                    View mDecorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
                    Toast.makeText (activity, "TWO" + strl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
                }

            }
        }, "ok");
```

But it does not work, please guide me .

Comment: @HemantParmar i already mension that its does work because of my class does  NOT have activity please understand

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    adjustFullScreen(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        adjustFullScreen(getResources().getConfiguration());
    }
}
private void adjustFullScreen(Configuration config) {
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    } else {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: but action bar over the element (e.g for action bar over the BUtton)

Answer (score 0):

change your application level theme to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Comment: first read my question and ans please  . .i want to change the activity full screen mode without using XML and requestWindowFeature.